# Problem with installing Fedora 26 : "Error checking storage configuration" (Using Live USB)

Tags: fedora, system-installation, dual-boot, troubleshooting

I am on HP desktop with basic config as follow :

> OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
>   Version   10.0.10586 Build 10586
>   Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3220
>   CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3300 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4
>   Logical Processor(s) BIOS
>   Version/Date  AMI 8.06, 01/24/13 SMBIOS
>   Version   2.7 Secure Boot
>   State Unsupported Installed Physical
>   Memory (RAM)  6.00 GB Total Physical
>   Memory    3.39 GB Available Physical
>   Memory    1.67 GB Total Virtual
>   Memory    6.89 GB Available Virtual
>   Memory    5.07 GB

I am trying to make it dual-bootable with Fedora 26. I have made a Live USB with media writer and when I am installing it on the configuration page, it is always giving me "Error checking storage configuration" no matter what I am doing. I have initially used windows disk management tool to create 25 GB of "unallocated space" from my C: drive (boot). This 25 GB of "unallocated space" is shown by the Anaconda Installer but when I click on "Done" it asks me to reclaim space as there is 0 "free space". After which I deleted one whole partition of 175 GB hoping it might solve the issue. But it is still giving me the same problem. I have attached screenshot of the error.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I tired deleting partition from Anaconda installer which failed to do it and had to do it using windows Disk management (Might be the issue?).

Current Partition Setup : [image: image description]

I have tried many forums and not able to find a solution to it. This is my first time moving to Linux system and creating Dual-Bootable system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not an answer to you question (AFAICT, what you're doing should just work) but if this is your first experience with Linux, you may find it easier to install Fedora in a VM with VirtualBox or similar.  That would give you a good starting point for learning Linux with, without having to solve weird installation errors as your very first exposure to Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to try that anyways if I am not able to sort this issue. But I am doing this because I am following a course and the instructor is using Fedora with a Kali on VM in it. I don't think that would be possible on VM, kinda like inception than :P

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about VirtualBox but Linux's KVM definitely supports nested VMs.  So if VirtualBox supports it, you could run Fedora in Vbox, then a KVM VM of kali inside that.   You'd need to choose a virtual-CPU type for the Vbox VM that has virtualisation extensions - Intel VT or AMD-V